# Debug MapReduce program in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, hadoop, mapreduce

I am using Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce SDK to build a Map/Reduce program. Its working fine. But I am not able to figure out, How to debug the Map and Reduce function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StreamingUnit class supports debugging of a Map/Reduce program with simple in-process execution of map-reduce components.

```
var output = StreamingUnit.Execute<MyMapper, MyReducer>( string[] input);
```

See the complete details [here](http://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Debugging&referringTitle=Map/Reduce).